# Parse Delimited CSV in .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, csv

I have a text file that is in a comma separated format, delimited by `"` on most fields.  I am trying to get that into something I can enumerate through (Generic Collection, for example).  I don't have control over how the file is output nor the character it uses for the delimiter.

In this case, the fields are separated by a comma and text fields are enclosed in `"` marks.  The problem I am running into is that some fields have quotation marks in them (i.e. 8`"` Tray) and are accidentally being picked up as the next field.  In the case of numeric fields, they don't have quotes around them, but they do start with a + or a - sign (depicting a positive/negative number).

I was thinking of a RegEx, but my skills aren't that great so hopefully someone can come up with some ideas I can try.  There are about 19,000 records in this file, so I am trying to do it as efficiently as possible.  Here are a couple of example rows of data:

```
"00","000000112260   ","Pie Pumpkin                             ","RET","6.99 ","     ","ea ",+0000000006.99000
"00","000000304078   ","Pie Apple caramel                       ","RET","9.99 ","     ","ea ",+0000000009.99000
"00","StringValue here","8" Tray of Food                             ","RET","6.99 ","     ","ea ",-00000000005.3200
```

There are a lot more fields, but you can get the picture....

I am using VB.NET and I have a generic List setup to accept the data.  I have tried using [CSVReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) and it seems to work well until you hit a record like the 3rd one (with a quote in the text field).  If I could somehow get it to handle the additional quotes, than the CSVReader option will work great.

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to have properly formatted CSV files to start with.

Comment: Double quotes within a quoted string are supposed to be escaped by doubling. So "8" Tray of Food" is not allowed in the format.

This way, a string like hi","there can exist. Escaped and quoted, it becomes "hi"",""there". Without the doubling, it becomes "hi","there" which looks like two strings.

Comment: I agree with both of the comments above, but unfortunately, I don't have control over how the file is exported.  That's the way it comes out of the software.

Comment: Please, please, please don't roll your own CSV parser, and certainly don't use RegEx for this. Use the free, open source, battle-tested FileHelpers library. http://www.filehelpers.com

Comment: filehelpers source is no longer available :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/blog/Parse+CSV+Files+In+C+And+ASPNET.aspx):

```
Encoding fileEncoding = GetFileEncoding(csvFile);
// get rid of all doublequotes except those used as field delimiters
string fileContents = File.ReadAllText(csvFile, fileEncoding);
string fixedContents = Regex.Replace(fileContents, @"([^\^,\r\n])""([^$,\r\n])", @"$1$2");
using (CsvReader csv =
       new CsvReader(new StringReader(fixedContents), true))
{
       // ... parse the CSV
```

Comment: This works pretty good, but for some reason, it screws up on a name like:  Product "A" Name     I am sure it has to do with the RegEx, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: See my answer below for how I was able to implement this.

Comment: This is a good solution that I used but the GetFileEncoding function wasn't made available. I'll post it later if anyone needs it.

Answer (score 82):

I recommend looking at the [TextFieldParserClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx) in .Net. You need to include

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
```

Here's a quick sample:

```
        Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(FileName)
        Dim CurrentRecord As String() ' this array will hold each line of data
        afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        afile.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

        ' parse the actual file
        Do While Not afile.EndOfData
            Try
                CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
            Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
                Stop
            End Try
        Loop
```

Comment: FYI: TextFieldParser implements IDisposable and should be wrapped in a 'using' statement or explicitly disposed.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if there are line breaks inside quoted fields.  Bummer.

Comment: Does anyone have any idea why such a general purpose class would live in the VisualBasic namespace?

Comment: 2021 checking in -- Avi's answer is still the best solution I found for parsing CSV where some fields have embedded commas, using Framework 4.6. Came looking here because other methods were not as easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

As this link says... [Don't roll your own CSV parser!](http://secretgeek.net/csv_trouble.asp)

Use TextFieldParser as Avi suggested. Microsoft has already done this for you. If you ended up writing one, and you find a bug in it, consider replacing it instead of fixing the bug. I did just that recently and it saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 5):

Give a look to the [FileHelpers library](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Looks good, but I found it very frustrating to use. Lack of support for auto-properties instead of private fields is very clumsy.

Comment: And this wasn't a factor in the original question, but that page says that FileHelpers uses dynamic code generation.  That means it's not useful in some constrained environments (MonoTouch, for me).

Answer (score 5):

You could give [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) (a library I maintain) a try and it's available via [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/CsvHelper). It follows the [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) standard for CSV. It will be able to handle any content inside of a field including commas, quotes, and new lines.

CsvHelper is simple to use, but it's also easy to configure it to work with many different types of delimited files.

```
CsvReader csv = new CsvReader( streamToFile );
IEnumerable<MyObject> myObjects = csv.GetRecords<MyObject>();
```

If you want to read CSV files on a lower level, you can use the parser directly, which will return each row as a string array.

```
var parser = new CsvParser( myTextReader );
while( true )
{
    string[] line = parser.ReadLine();
    if( line == null )
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: plus it is the fastest general purpose csv parser I have seen so far.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this as an answer so I can explain how I did it and why....  The answer from Mitch Wheat was the one that gave me the best solution for this case and I just had to modify it slightly due to the format this data was exported in.

Here is the VB Code:

```
Dim fixedContents As String = Regex.Replace(
                            File.ReadAllText(csvFile, fileEncoding),
                            "(?<!,)("")(?!,)", 
                            AddressOf ReplaceQuotes)
```

The RegEx that was used is what I needed to change because certain fields had non-escaped quotes in them and the RegEx provided didn't seem to work on all examples.  This one uses 'Look Ahead' and 'Look Behind' to see if the quote is just after a comma or just before.  In this case, they are both negative (meaning show me where the double quote is not before or after a comma).  This should mean that the quote is in the middle of a string.

In this case, instead of doing a direct replacement, I am using the function ReplaceQuotes to handle that for me.  The reason I am using this is because I needed a little extra logic to detect whether it was at the beginning of a line.  If I would have spent even more time on it, I am sure I could have tweaked the RegEx to take into consideration the beginning of the line (using MultiLine, etc) but when I tried it quickly, it didn't seem to work at all.

With this in place, using CSV reader on a 32MB CSV file (about 19000 rows), it takes about 2 seconds to read the file, perform the regex, load it into the CSV Reader, add all the data to my generic class and finish.  Real quick!!

Answer (score 1):

RegEx to exclude first and last quote would be `(?<!^)(?<!,)("")(?!,)(?!$)`. Of course, you need to use RegexOptions.Multiline.

That way there is no need for evaluator function. My code replaces undesired double quotes with single quotes.

Complete C# code is as below.

```
string fixedCSV = Regex.Replace(
            File.ReadAllText(fileName),
            @"(?<!^)(?<!;)("")(?!;)(?!$)", "'", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least ODBC drivers for CSV files. But there are different flavors of CSV.

What produced these files? It's not unlikely that there's a matching driver based on the requirements of the source application.

Comment: It is an old DOS based accounting package called Business Vision Delta.  Unfortunately, the company has been sold to new vendors and they don't support the old DOS stuff any longer.  This is the only way I can extract the data to integrate into newer software.

Comment: Can you tell what kind of data tables it uses? Maybe dbfs? Also, try just opening the CSV files with Excel, Access, whatever other apps you have that can import CSV. Try to avoid writing software as a first option.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with CSVReader is that the quote in the third record isn't escaped with another quote (aka double quoting).  If you don't escape them, then how would you expect to handle ", in the middle of a text field?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

(I did end up having to work with files (with different delimiters) but the quote characters inside a text value weren't escaped and I ended up writing my own custom parser.  I do not know if this was absolutely necessary or not.)

Comment: That is my problem...  I can't escape them.  I don't have control over how the file is exported.  I'm trying to get away from writing a parser that goes character by character to check if there is a comma after a quote, etc.  but it may come down to that.

Comment: Well, if you go the route of making your own (I'm still convinced there's a solution somewhere that can handle this case), just be sure to validate the field count and data as best as you can.  (I'd post mine but I did it at work.)

Answer (score 0):

The logic of this custom approach is: Read through file 1 line at a time, split each line on the comma, remove the first and last character (removing the outer quotes but not affecting any inside quotes), then adding the data to your generic list. It's short and very easy to read and work with.

```
        Dim fr As StreamReader = Nothing
        Dim FileString As String = ""
        Dim LineItemsArr() as String

        Dim FilePath As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("YourFile.csv")

        fr = New System.IO.StreamReader(FilePath)

        While fr.Peek <> -1
            FileString = fr.ReadLine.Trim

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FileString) Then Continue While 'Empty Line

            LineItemsArr = FileString.Split(",")

            For Each Item as String In LineItemsArr
                'If every item will have a beginning and closing " (quote) then you can just
                'cut the first and last characters of the string here.
                'i.e.  UpdatedItems = Item. remove first and last character

                'Then stick the data into your Generic List (Of String()?)
            Next
        End While
```

Comment: Or before stripping the outer quotes, use this as a test to do string processing, or number processing (if needs be).

Comment: This doesn't handle data where the separator character is in the data

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static Encoding GetFileEncoding(String fileName)
    {
        Encoding Result = null;
        FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(fileName);
        FileStream FS = null;

        try
        {
            FS = FI.OpenRead();
            Encoding[] UnicodeEncodings = { Encoding.BigEndianUnicode, Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8 };
            for (int i = 0; Result == null && i < UnicodeEncodings.Length; i++)
            {
                FS.Position = 0;
                byte[] Preamble = UnicodeEncodings[i].GetPreamble();
                bool PreamblesAreEqual = true;
                for (int j = 0; PreamblesAreEqual && j < Preamble.Length; j++)
                {
                    PreamblesAreEqual = Preamble[j] == FS.ReadByte();
                }
                if (PreamblesAreEqual)
                {
                    Result = UnicodeEncodings[i];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (FS != null)
            {
                FS.Close();
            }
        }

        if (Result == null)
        {
            Result = Encoding.Default;
        }

        return Result;
    }
```