# "is not a valid name" error while retrieving data from csv/txt file using oledb

Tags: vb.net, csv, oledb, jet

I retrieving data from a csv/txt file using oledb driver

```
ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " & System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) & "; Extended Properties = ""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) & "]"
```

In the last line I am getting following error if the filename is large

**is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long.**

My question -
Is there any limit to filename or the select query or there is some pattern which I need to follow?

Comment: I am not getting what you trying to say. can you explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly found out what the problem was but it is clear that long file name was creating problem so here is [what I did](http://utkarshpuranik.com/2010/01/07/is-not-a-valid-name-error-while-retrieving-data-from-csv-file-using-oledb-solution)

```
ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " & System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) & "; Extended Properties = ""Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited"""

    '=================================== OleDB Supports fixed length file name. Handle long file names'
    Dim OldFileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName)
    Dim NewFileName As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 10) + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(OldFileName)
    Dim rootPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(strFileName) + "/"

    'Rename file name'
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(rootPath + OldFileName, NewFileName)
    strFileName = rootPath + NewFileName
    '===================================='

    Dim strQuery As String
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & System.IO.Path.GetFileName(strFileName) & "]"

    'Revert rename file name'
    '===================================================================='
    My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameFile(rootPath + NewFileName, OldFileName)
    strFileName = rootPath + OldFileName
    '===================================================================='
```

I just renamed the file with a new Guid while I am retrieving the data after renamed it back to original file name.

This is not exactly what I wanted, I am still looking for a better solution. Please post if someone find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Having just struggled with this, I found that *no part* of the file path or name could contain spaces or single quotes or the file path would be determined to be invalid. This applied no matter what qualification or escaping of the name I tried.

After I removed all spaces and single quotes, everything was fine. Eg.

**Invalid:**

```
"C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Data\User''s Folder\Import Data.csv"
```

**Valid:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Data\Users-Folder\ImportData.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [answer stolen shamelessly from Avi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net/736647#736647) which is why it's community wiki:

I recommend looking at the [TextFieldParserClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx) built into .Net rather than using Oledb. You need to include

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
```

Here's a quick sample:

```
        Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New _
          FileIO.TextFieldParser(FileName)
        Dim CurrentRecord As String() ' this array will hold each line of data '
        afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        afile.Delimiters = New String() {","}
        afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

        ' parse the actual file '
        Do While Not afile.EndOfData
            Try
                CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
            Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
                Stop
            End Try
        Loop
```

I have already upvoted the [answer I have borrowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net/736647#736647)

Answer (score 1):

Some experimentation has shown that the file name without the extension must not contain a ".". So, `MyData.csv` is a valid file name, but `My.Data.csv` is not.

Comment: I don't exactly remember if filename contained a "." or not as this problem occurred sometime ago but that could have been the problem.