# Parsing csv file with commas and quotes as deliminators Pin

Tags: c#, string

So Im reading a csv file and splitting the string with "," as the deliminator

but some of them have quotes as to not split the specific field because it has a comma in it.

1530,Pasadena CA,"2008, 05/01","2005, 12/14"

with just comma it would be:

1530
Pasadena CA
"2008
05/01"
"2005
12/14"

I need it to take commas into consideration when splitting so its like this

1530
Pasadena CA
"2008 05/01"
"2005 12/14"

Comment: That's a common problem, solved in many places.  Did you search google or CodeProject for a CSV parser written in C#?  That would likely answer the question for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) for a library that offers quick and easy CSV reading.

Comment: Trying not to use an external library, I was thinking something like

Comment: strLine = strLine.Replace("\\"", "\'\'");

Comment: so replace "" with '' then replace , with " then replace "" with , eliminating the quotes but keeping the commas

Comment: If you just remove the quotes, then you're altering the CSV.  You could end up reading it incorrectly.  There are a lot of things to be careful with, regarding CSVs.  I would look at the library.  There's nothing wrong with using it.  Its using the MIT license, so its not a problem to include it in your deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the link, this library works beautifully. No need to reinvent the wheel ;)

Answer (score 0):

While it still may be a new reference, there is a class within the Visual Basic assemblies that should handle this well.  At least then you know it's a part of the framework.  You can find details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx