# How to keep quotes when parsing csv file?

Tags: c#, csv, double-quotes, textfieldparser

I am using   `Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser` to read a csv file, edit it , then parse it.

The problem is the quotes are not being kept after parsing.

I tried using `parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;` but it does not seem to keep the quotes for some reason.

This issue breaks when a field contains a quote for example :
 Before

```
 "some, field"
```

After

```
 some, field
```

As two seperate fields

Here is my method

```
public static void CleanStaffFile()
    {
        String path = @"C:\file.csv";
        String dpath = String.Format(@"C:\file_{0}.csv",DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyHHmmss"));
        List<String> lines = new List<String>();

        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(path))
            {
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
                parser.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };

                while (!parser.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] parts = parser.ReadFields();

                    if (parts == null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if ((parts[12] != "") && (parts[12] != "*,116"))
                    {
                        parts[12] = parts[12].Substring(0, 3);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        parts[12] = "0";
                    }

                    lines.Add(string.Join(",", parts));
                }
            }

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(dpath, false))
            {
                foreach (String line in lines)
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
            }

        }

        MessageBox.Show("CSV file successfully processed :\n");
    }
```

Comment: If the field qualified with in quotes it treats the field as one data item. If the quotes part of the data you will need to use a different text qualifier.

Comment: There are [a lot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865747/parsing-csv-file-enclosed-with-quotes-in-c-sharp) of [these questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000415/parsing-csv-file-with-commas-and-quotes-as-deliminators-pin)

Comment: So you want to have quotes after you have modified it at `string.Join(",", parts)`? Then it's easy since only fields which contain the separator were wrapped in quotes before. Just add them again before the `String.Join`.

Comment: Please show some of the offending data to make the question easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to have quotes after you have modified it at `string.Join(",", parts)`? Then it's easy since only fields which contain the separator were wrapped in quotes before. Just add them again before the `String.Join`.

So before (and desired):

```
"some, field"
```

after(not desired):

```
some, field
```

This should work:

```
string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
// insert your logic here ....
var newFields = fields 
    .Select(f => f.Contains(",") ? string.Format("\"{0}\"", f) : f);
lines.Add(string.Join(",", newFields));
```

**Edit**

> I would like to keep quotes even if doesn't contain a comma

Then it's even easier:

```
var newFields = fields.Select(f => string.Format("\"{0}\"", f));
```

Comment: What logic i need to insert there? I would like to keep quotes even if doesnt not contains commas thanks

Comment: @meda: that's just the part from you that i've omitted. I must admit that i'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve. However, i think it is not related to the problem how to keep the quotes that were removed. So `// insert your logic here ....` is what starts with `if (parts == null)` in your code. **Edited** my answer according to "keep quotes even if doesn't  contain quotes".

Comment: I meant to say even if does not contain comma

Answer (score 0):

The [`TextFieldParser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.hasfieldsenclosedinquotes.aspx) property is used as follows, from the MSDN page:

> If the property is True, the parser assumes that fields are enclosed in quotation marks (" ") and may contain line endings.
>
> If a field is enclosed in quotation marks, for example, `abc, "field2a,field2b", field3` and this property is `True`, then all text enclosed in quotation marks will be returned as is; this example would return `abc|field2a,field2b|field3`. Setting this property to False would make this example return `abc|"field2a|field2b"|field3`.

The quotes will indicate the start and end of a field, which may then contain the character(s) used to normally separate fields. If your data itself has quotes, you need to set `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to `false`.

If your data fields can contain both separators and quotes, you will need to start escaping quotes before parsing, which is a problem. Basicly you're going beyond the capabilities of a simple CSV file.