# FileHelpers Nonstandard Embedded Quotes in CSV

Tags: .net, csv, filehelpers

We are using FileHelpers to parse a CSV file. Unfortunately, we've run into an issue with data being read into unexpected columns, since the CSV file does not escape embedded quotes:

```
1,"SURNAME, FIRSTNAME "NICKNAME"",2
```

instead of doubling them as is usual:

```
1,"SURNAME, FIRSTNAME ""NICKNAME""",2
```

We are not at liberty to change the CSV file, so it is necessary to use the file as-is. Is it possible to do this with with a stock build of FileHelpers? If not, is there another .NET CSV library that supports this format out of the box?

Comment: Do your CSV files at least escape commas in the text? Or can you at least guarantee that no commas will ever be present in the text?

Comment: Unfortunately, commas are present in the text (including in the improperly escaped field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the post here, specifically @Mitch Wheat's answer and the OP's own solution:
[Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net/743863#743863)