# How to convert csv string to list in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, csv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net)

Hi,

How can I convert a csv string into a list in vb.net?

Comment: Did you Google this before you asked it?

Comment: Depends on the "type" of CSV string. For a very primitive string without embedded separators or quotes, `string.split` will work. However, this is not an answer because it's about as "correct" as using a regex to parse HTML. I am pretty sure the VisualBasic namespace contains support for CSV file/stream parsing, so that would be a place to look.

Comment: See [SO: Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net) It's not an exact duplicate, because that deals with a file, but the same approach *of the 2nd answer* which uses [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) can be given a stream and a stream can be created directly from a string with [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) The first reply in the post also shows a "safer" method of manual parsing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want something like this...

```
Dim MyString as String = "one,two,three,four,five"
Dim MyArray() as String = Mystring.Split(",")
Dim MyList as List(Of String) = MyArray.ToList()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Breaks for `"one,two",two,three`

Comment: On problem, I am getting an error saying Array.tolist() is not a member of system.array. I am using .net framework 4.0

Comment: This is Helpful

Comment: @chobo or anybody reading this, One need to import System.LinQ

Answer (score 4):

using Linq:

```
Dim parts As String = "1,2,3,4"
Dim itemsList As List(Of String)

itemsList = (From s In parts.Split(",")
            Select s).ToList()
```

Gives you a list with 4 items

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the split function.

```
    Dim a As String
    a = "data1,2,3,4,5"

    Dim b() As String
    b = a.Split(",")

    Dim c As List(Of String)
    c = b.ToList()
```

c will be a list of strings

Comment: Breaks for `"one,two",two,three`

Comment: You may code like this too:
`Dim a As String
 a = "data1,2,3,4,5"
Dim c As List(Of String)
c = a.Split(",").ToList()`