# How do I read data from a CSV file and store the info Into an array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, csv

I have two columns in a CSV file and I need to store each column in a separate array.

```
Name,AvalibilityAsBoolean
---------------------------
Vagarth Gaurav,True
Dhananjay Menon,False
```

I would like to have one array for name, and another array for availability as a boolean value stored similar to below.

```
Name(0) = "Vagarth Gaurav"
Name(1) = "Dhananjay Menon"
Available(0) = True
Available(1) = False
```

The only problem is reading the CSV and storing the strings and booleans into the proper arrays.

Please help, I am new to VB. I am using Visual Basic 2010

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this question has been asked before, but this should help.  Utilizing the [TextFieldParser Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakac7e6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do the parsing for you makes it easy.  Code for managing the two arrays is displayed in this code example too.

```
    Dim arrName() As String
    Dim arrValue() As String

    Using ioReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\test\test.csv")

        ioReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        ioReader.SetDelimiters(",")

        While Not ioReader.EndOfData

            Dim arrCurrentRow As String() = ioReader.ReadFields()

            If arrName Is Nothing Then

                ReDim Preserve arrName(0)
                ReDim Preserve arrValue(0)

                arrName(0) = arrCurrentRow(0)
                arrValue(0) = arrCurrentRow(1)

            Else

                ReDim Preserve arrName(arrName.Length)
                ReDim Preserve arrValue(arrValue.Length)

                arrName((arrName.Length - 1)) = arrCurrentRow(0)
                arrValue((arrValue.Length - 1)) = arrCurrentRow(1)

            End If

        End While
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sData() As String
Dim arrName, arrValue as New List(Of String)()

Using sr As New StreamReader(sFile)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
        sData = sr.ReadLine().Split(","c)

        arrName.Add(sData(0).Trim())
        arrValue.Add(sData(1).Trim())
    End While
End Using
```

You maybe want to store your value as a `Boolean` (available, notAvailable). You can do something like:

```
Dim arrValue As New List(Of Boolean)()
...

    arrValue.Add(Not sData(1).Trim().ToUpper().StartsWith("NOT"))
```