# VB.net delimiter "","" split strings

Tags: vb.net, csv, split, delimiter

I'm using the below code to split a line into an array but some of the elements contain commas like the example below.

Current code : `output.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(New Char() {","c}))`

Every element has "" around it in the CSV and I can't change it as it is from a supplier.   I'm splitting the line into an array then removing the " using this.

```
'data(iRow)(0) = data(iRow)(0).Replace(Chr(34), "")
```

I'm running into problems because the elements like `my,park` that need to remain same.

Example Data : The data is read like this from the CSV/Text file

```
"my,park","mydate","my school","myhome"
```

My full function is below if that helps, been stuck on it for 2 days now.

```
Dim output As New ArrayList()
Using sr As StreamReader = New StreamReader(fileName)
      While Not sr.EndOfStream
            output.Add(sr.ReadLine().Split(New Char() {","c}))
      End While
End Using
Return output
```

How can I complete this efficiently and get the correct output?  The process is tripping up with the element containing commas and I don't know how to split on ","

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the libraries Linq-To-Excel or FileHelpers. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You can also use the `TextFieldParser` class to do this.

Comment: I've never done it before and am a little lost now.  Should I not just be able to split the string on ","  ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Delimited CSV in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net)

Comment: A better duplicate might be [Reading a CSV file in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405038/reading-a-csv-file-in-net).

Comment: Split by `""","""` (this will split by quotes and comma). Not until then replace the quotes in the splitted lines `Replace("""", "")`. Add the replaced result to your ArrayList.

Comment: Do you have an example on this? Alex B

Comment: Yes: [Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FaLimN). The function SimulateFileStream is just for test since I could not use real files.