# vb.net array from comma separated strings

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I'd like to get a String array from a String that is delimited with spaces (" ") and commas. Is there a clever way to do this?

For example, if the string was:

> cat dog giraffe "big elephant" snake

I'd like the resulting array to contain strings

> cat
>
> dog
>
> giraffe
>
> big elephant
>
> snake

I know I could do a Split(str, " ") but the result would differ from what I wanted. I've never used RegEx, but I have a hunch that the solution might have something to do with it.

Comment: Why not to a `.Replace()` and then `.Split()`? Regex is overkill here.

Comment: Replacing what, @DanielShillcock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treating the input as space-delimited CSV can greatly simplify the task:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser
...
Dim s As String = "cat dog giraffe ""big elephant"" snake"
Dim afile As FileIO.TextFieldParser = New FileIO.TextFieldParser(New System.IO.StringReader(s))
Dim CurrentRecord As String()
afile.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
afile.Delimiters = New String() {" "}
afile.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
Do While Not afile.EndOfData
    Try
        CurrentRecord = afile.ReadFields
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join("; ", CurrentRecord))
    Catch ex As FileIO.MalformedLineException
        Stop
    End Try
Loop
```

It prints `cat; dog; giraffe; big elephant; snake`.

The code is adapted from [*Parse Delimited CSV in .NET*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736629/parse-delimited-csv-in-net).

Comment: Thanks. That'll do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this :

```
Const data = "åäöÄ åäöÄ ""åäöÄ åäöÄ"" åäöÄ"

Dim matches = Regex.Matches (data, "\p{L}+|""\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*""")

For Each m As Match in matches
    Console.WriteLine (m.Value.Trim(""""))
Next
```

The regex works as follow :

- match either **\p{L}+** which means one or more letter as much as possible
- or *(denoted by the **|**)* match **"\p{L}+(?: \p{L}+)*"** in detail :

  - **"** match a quote
  - **\p{L}+** match one or more letter as much as possible
  - the **(?: \p{L}+)*** means a group which doesn't result in a capture repeated zero or more times as much as possible
    This group consist in a space followed by one or more letter as much as possible
  - finally match the closing quote **"**

Then we just have to `Trim` the resulting match to eliminate the potential startind/ending quote

*Note : see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) for more info about `\p{L}`*

Comment: What about non-english text? Does it melt down when åäö is inputted?

Comment: It was melting down, it wasn't stated as a requirement though but I've editted the code to support them

Comment: Depends where in alphabet öä and z are located. In our language, z is next to s (...pqrszšžt...) and even t, u etc are ignored :)

Comment: @Sehnsucht Interesting, thanks for pointing out. Do unicode letters include numerics and punctuation marks? (eg for "big.0-eléphant" case)